# Cannot turn response.text into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the Python request module and having trouble converting my response.text into a Python dictionary.

```
def my_function():
    url = API_URI["test"]
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}    
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(api), headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    dict = r.json()
    return dict
my_function()
```

Here is the printed response from r.text

{"subscriptionId":"8530989","profile":{"customerProfileId":"507869879","customerPaymentProfileId":"512588514"},"refId":"12345","messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}

And the error

```
   raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried both json.loads(r.text) and r.json()

I see that the error wants me to decode, but where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error points out, the data should be decoded using `utf-8-sig` instead of the default `utf-8` decoding.

something like this:

```py
decoded_data = r.text.encode().decode('utf-8-sig')
return json.loads(decoded_data)
```

would probably work to load this data into a dictionary.

Edit:

Setting

```py
r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
```

before running `r.json()` should also fix this.

Comment: Or set `r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'` most likely

Comment: Good point @ChatterOne thanks - I updated my answer to include this